# Get middle range of 4 time

Tags: mysql, select, range

[image]

I have 2 tables stored data every 5 minutes, how can I make a query to join and select time_begin and time_end of table 2 between table 1 time range?

**For ex:**

```
table1: time_begin: 20:01:00, time_end: 20:24:00
table 2: time_begin: 20:00:00, time_end: 20:25:00
```

=> I need select time_begin: 20:01:00, time_end: 20:24:00

```
table1: time_begin: 20:01:00, time_end: 20:24:00
table2: time_begin: 20:02:00, time_end: 20:25:00
```

=> I need select  time_begin: 20:02:00, time_end: 20:24:00

```
table1: time_begin: 20:01:00, time_end: 20:24:00
table2: time_begin: 20:02:00, time_end: 20:23:00
```

=> I need select time_begin: 20:02:00, time_end: 20:23:00

Comment: You write code: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GREATEST(t1.time_begin, t2.time_begin)
LEAST(t1.time_end, t2.time_end)
```